# Recompiling Javascript ES6 to ES5 code when the code is a string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, file-conversion

I tried using facebook's Regenerator to convert ES6 code to ES5 code.
The code I need to convert is produced by React-ace editor and it is a string. Regenerator does not recognize strings and simply returns them as it was.

I tried using eval() and new Function(), both of which will be executed when passed into regenerator.compile("whatever code I need to compile").code, and the value returned will just be the return value of the executed code.

Is there a way to convert the string produced by React-ace(or any browser text editor) and converted it to ES5 code? Are there any other libraries that allows you to convert ES6 syntax to ES5?

Working Example with local function declaration:

```
let testFunction = (b) => {

  let a = (c) => {
    return c
  }

  return b;
}

let regenCode = require('regenerator').compile(testFunction).code;
console.log(regenCode);
```

this will produce:

```
function testFunction(b) {

   var a = function (c) {
     return c;
   } 

   return b;
}
```

Trying to do:

```
let regenCode = require('regenerator').compile("let testFunction = (b) => { let a = (c) => { return c } return b; }");
```

but this will simply give the string back to me

Comment: please share your code here

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: regenerator only converts generators and async functions to ES5, not any other ES6 features.

Comment: apologize for not sharing code the first time, it's my first question on stack overflow

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=DYUwLgBGIM5gYgVwHYGMwEsD2yIF4IAKAIwEp8A-CAbwChaIJRIBDfI1cvKuxxgJ3CJ-uVAwgBfegKEiIxANy0pQA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use Regenerator programmatically with an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), not with a string.

From the [Regenerator documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regenerator):

> AST transformation:
>
> ```
> var recast = require("recast");
> var ast = recast.parse(es6Source);
> ast = require("regenerator").transform(ast);
> var es5Source = recast.print(ast);
> ```

In your case, you'd have to do something like:

```
var recast = require("recast");
var ast = recast.parse("let testFunction = (b) => { let a = (c) => { return c }; return b; }");
ast = require("regenerator").transform(ast);
var es5Source = recast.print(ast);
```

Comment: *"You can only use Regenerator programmatically with an AST, not with a string."* The documentation you linked to clearly shows that it's possible to pass a string. It's before the AST example.